# Android Vector decrease size to button

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I have to show a vector in button as drawable. I have tried to reduce the size of vector to small icon size (*40dp x 40dp* ) but its not working. Vector image is too large.

Drawable vector is  ***wfnt_users_svg.xml***

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="640dp"
        android:height="512dp"
    android:viewportWidth="640.0"
    android:viewportHeight="512.0"    >
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M96,224c35.3,0 64,-28.7 64,-64s-28.7,-64 -64,-64 -64,28.7 -64,64 28.7,64 64,64zM544,224c35.3,0 64,-28.7 64,-64s-28.7,-64 -64,-64 -64,28.7 -64,64 28.7,64 64,64zM576,256h-64c-17.6,0 -33.5,7.1 -45.1,18.6 40.3,22.1 68.9,62 75.1,109.4h66c17.7,0 32,-14.3 32,-32v-32c0,-35.3 -28.7,-64 -64,-64zM320,256c61.9,0 112,-50.1 112,-112S381.9,32 320,32 208,82.1 208,144s50.1,112 112,112zM396.8,288h-8.3c-20.8,10 -43.9,16 -68.5,16s-47.6,-6 -68.5,-16h-8.3C179.6,288 128,339.6 128,403.2L128,432c0,26.5 21.5,48 48,48h288c26.5,0 48,-21.5 48,-48v-28.8c0,-63.6 -51.6,-115.2 -115.2,-115.2zM173.1,274.6C161.5,263.1 145.6,256 128,256L64,256c-35.3,0 -64,28.7 -64,64v32c0,17.7 14.3,32 32,32h65.9c6.3,-47.4 34.9,-87.3 75.2,-109.4z"/>
</vector>
```

My button is :

```
<Button
 android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
 android:layout_width="200dp"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:text="  Log-in To Staff"
 android:paddingRight="20dp"
 android:textAllCaps="false"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:enabled="false"
 android:background="@drawable/bg_layout"
 android:id="@+id/asl_relogin"
 android:drawableLeft="@drawable/wfnt_users_svg"  />
```

I have also tried :

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
 android:width="40dp"
 android:height="40dp"
```

But still the problem is same, vector is not able to fit to button. I have also tried ImageButton, but unable to set Desired Text to ImageButton.

I have to set about 50 Vectors of same dimensions as above mentioned vector in various buttons.

**I can not use (Image with textview) or other Combinations**.

*I there any way to fit the vector to button or reduce the size of vector to 40dp x 40 dp ?*

Comment: editing size of the drawable doesn't work with buttons, you could use images view beside the buttons and wrap it in a linear layout.

Comment: i can not modify more than 50 buttons in all activities with their respective layouts with image view with linear layout. is there any better way to do ?  like reducing vector size to 40dp by  40dp ??